# Duplicate join table records being created with has_many checkboxes, can't uncheck/destroy them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, associations, has-many-through, join

I am following the **HABTM Railscast #17** on using checkboxes to create associated records using a join table.

I finally got my records to save to the join table....but I can't control them by checking or unchecking a box....meaning unchecking the record does nothing and leaving the record checked makes ANOTHER duplicate record.

I have 3 tables.

```
 :project has_many :restrictions, :through => :project_restrictions
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have an array of checkboxes that I can check to create **:project_restrictions.**..or, if I uncheck them, the remove the **:project_restriction** record.

Right now it just keeps saving multiple records and does not delete them if I uncheck one.

I have put all my logic in the ProjectsController and am running the method for adding the **:project_restrictions** through a custom PATCH method called **"add_restrictions"**.  Should this be a POST? I can't figure out if I'm PATCHING Project by adding associated records or POSTING just the associated records.

my join table has an **:id** and no **:timestamps** .... I don't know if this matters....obviously, I'm new.

I am using rails 4.

**MY MODELS**

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :project_restrictions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :restrictions, :through => :project_restrictions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_restrictions, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank


 class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :projects, :through => :project_restrictions
  has_many :project_restrictions, dependent: :destroy

 class ProjectRestriction< ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :restriction
  belongs_to :project
 end
```

**My PATCH Controller Method to Create Associated Records **

```
 def add_restrictions
  @diet = Restriction.k1.order(:name) 
  @project = Project.find(params[:p]) 

  params[:project][:restriction_ids].reject!(&:empty?).each do |restriction| 

  @proj_rule = ProjectRestriction.create!(:project_id => @project.id, :restriction_id => restriction) 
  @proj_rule.save

  end
  respond_to do |format| 

 format.html { redirect_to t1s3_path(:p => @project.id ) , 
 notice: 'Success! You added restrictions!' } 
 format.json {} 

 end 
 end
```

**And my form**

```
   <%= form_for @project, url: add_restrictions_path(:p => @project.id) do |f| %>

   <div class=" fields ">
       <%= hidden_field_tag "project[restriction_ids][]", nil %>
            <% @diet.each do |restriction| %>

              <%= check_box_tag  "project[restriction_ids][]", restriction.id,          
           @project.restriction_ids.include?(restriction.id), id: dom_id(restriction)%> 
           <%= label_tag dom_id(restriction), restriction.name %><br>

           <% end %>

         </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my Models to have "uniq and inverse_of ....however I'm still creating duplicate records and unable to destroy them by unchecking the checkbox

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :project_restrictions -> { uniq }, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :project
  has_many :restrictions, -> { uniq }, through: :project_restrictions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_restrictions, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank


 class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :projects,  -> { uniq }, through: :project_restrictions
  has_many :project_restrictions,   -> { uniq }, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :restriction

 class ProjectRestriction< ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :restriction,  -> { uniq }, inverse_of: :project_restrictions
    belongs_to :project, -> { uniq }, inverse_of: :project_restrictions
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

change this in your **add_restrictions** method and try

```
def add_restrictions
  @diet = Restriction.k1.order(:name) 
  @project = Project.find(params[:p]) 

   params[:project][:restriction_ids].reject!(&:empty?).each do |restriction| 
       @projectrestrictions = ProjectRestriction.all
       @projectrestrictions.each do |prj|
         if prj.restriction_id == restriction
           ProjectRestriction.destroy_all(prj.id)
         else
            @proj_rule = ProjectRestriction.create!(:project_id => @project.id, :restriction_id => restriction) 
            @proj_rule.save
         end
      end
  respond_to do |format| 

 format.html { redirect_to t1s3_path(:p => @project.id ) , 
 notice: 'Success! You added restrictions!' } 
 format.json {} 

 end 
 end
```

Comment: thank you...but I just get this "Missing template projects/add_restrictions, application/add_restrictions with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere did you get the same error before you just need to add this in place of that and keep remaining as same in that method i will update my answer please check it

Comment: that code is missing something...it kept calling for an other 'keyword_end'... when I added another `end` it says this "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"."

Comment: So I tried to manage the redirects and tried this: when  ` respond_to do |format| 

return redirect_to t1s3_path(:p => @project.id ) 
 flash[:notice] = "Updated Events!!!!"
 format.json {} 

 end 
 end
end` it saved, but it gave every record the same restriction_id ...so it doesn't really work.